# Trying to get multiple variable outputs in Python

Tags: python, variables, dataset, output

I have this problem with trying to figure how to change this code to something useable for me. I have created this combination below that gives me ADABTC, ADAETH, ADAUSDT, BCCBTC,...... and so on.
I'm trying to have each one of these feed into a reference field to pull this information.

```
alt = ["ADA", "BCC", "EOS"]
base = ["BTC", "ETH", "USDT"
alt_base = []
for x in alt:
   for y in base:
      alt_base.append(x + y)
```

I'm trying to get this to feed into as an independent into feeding for some data calls.

`"Variable" = client.get_orderbook_ticker(symbol = alt_base)` where I need this to basically end up with multiple version to be pulled from the source.

Didn't know if I could try something like

```
ada_btc = client.get_orderbook_ticker(symbol = "ADABTC")
ada_eth = client.get_orderbook_ticker(symbol = "ADAETH")
```

It doesn't have to list these out, but the variables would need to have those meanings.
So I could parse data from these feeds to get the info I need.
Figured something like this, but that doesn't work. I'm new to coding, but can't see some of the things that I need or what they are called to look them up.

```
coin[] = client.get_orderbook_ticker(symbol = alt_base)
```

Comment: It appears that you want the `itertools.product` method.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're getting close. Here's a list comprehension in IDLE:

```
>>> x = [letter for letter in "Hello World"]
>>> x
['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'W', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd']
```

You could use something similar to create a list of all the pairs:

```
coin[] = client.get_orderbook_ticker(symbol = alt_base)
```

becomes

```
coin = [client.get_orderbook_ticker(symbol=ab) for ab in alt_base]
```

If the objects don't have an easy way to track what pair they are, you could do:

```
coin = [ (ab , client.get_orderbook_ticker(symbol=ab)) for ab in alt_base]
```

to create a tuple of `(ab, whatever-that-object-is)`. Or, use a dict comprehension:

```
coin = {ab : client.get_orderbook_ticker(symbol=ab) for ab in alt_base}
```

Comment: Will check this out when I get home. But what this be called that I can look further into it to understand it better?

Comment: @Liamdaniel Generator Expressions, List Comprehensions, and Dictionary Comprehensions. https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html#generator-expressions-and-list-comprehensions   https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/